# on one reliable host, provide direct ssh passage between two roving hosts

Tags: ssh

I have two roving hosts, call them **home** and **office**.  They each sit behind firewalls, so aren't reachable, but they do have reliable outward connections.

On the net, I have one host, call it **intern**, which has a static IP address, so is reachable.

I want to connect to **office** from **home**, using **intern** as a hop.  The simple way is to have **office** do something like:

```
office$ ssh -R 2222:localhost:22 intern
```

...then, from **home**:

```
home$ ssh intern
intern$ ssh -p 2222 localhost
```

That works fine, gets me to a shell on **office**.  But what I want is to skip that "second shell" step, like:

- on **office**, connect to **intern**, and present a direct tunnel back to a port on **office**; this is the part I'm not clear on;
- then, from **home**: ssh to **intern** on an alternate port is forwarded directly to **office** without any intermediate connection.

My first guess:

```
home$ ssh -p 2222 intern
```

...throws "Connection refused", so that's wrong.  I've tried various arrangements of **-R**, **-D**, **-W**... obviously I'm thrashing.  Clue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's done through the fourth parameter of `-R`. When omitted (as in your example), it specifies that the remote port 2222 is bound to the server's "localhost" addresses only, which is why you get "Connection refused" when trying to connect to :2222 at the server's other addresses.

To bind the listener to all addresses, specify an `*` (empty value is also documented to work, as long as the `:` separator is present):

```
-R \*:2222:localhost:22
```

Note that the server may refuse to set up such a listener – you need to enable the `GatewayPorts` option in the `intern` server's configuration (not the client's) to allow this:

```
GatewayPorts clientspecified
```

After making the connection, run `netstat -ltn` or `ss -ltn` on the server to verify the result – it will exactly show you what **"local"** address (from the server's perspective) the new listener is bound to. (For `*` you should see two, one bound to 0.0.0.0:2222 for IPv4 and another bound to [::]:2222 for IPv6, and similarly the default "localhost" behavior also has two.)

```
$ ss -ltn "sport = :2222"
State       Recv-Q      Send-Q     Local Address:Port     Peer Address:Port
LISTEN      0           128            127.0.0.1:2222          0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN      0           128                [::1]:2222             [::]:*
```

Comment: Wow.  I was never going to guess anything like this.  To me the word "socket" translates as "written into some application somehow," so, not something I should look for as the answer to any shell-level operations; then the **-R** section of the manpage says nothing that would point me toward what you describe.

This does work exactly as you described.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, it's both. If you `ssh office`, the 'ssh' client uses a socket to make the connection – does that count as a "shell-level operation" because you ran 'ssh' from a shell, or does it count as "written into some application" because it's definitely 'ssh' and not the shell itself that does the work?

Answer (score 0):

One way is mentioned in the answer by @user1686 (use `-R \*:2222:localhost:22` and add `GatewayPorts clientspecified` to your `sshd` configuration in `intern`).

If for some reason you have no access to changing the `sshd` configuration in `intern`, you can combine the two `ssh` steps by using the `-J` argument (jumphost), basically like this:

```
home$ ssh -J intern -p 2222 localhost
```

To have this even more convenient, you can add an entry in your `~/.ssh/config` like this:

```
Host office
    ProxyJump intern
    Port 2222
    Hostname localhost
```

After this, you should be able to connect by simply doing:

```
home$ ssh office
```

Comment: I tried this and I'm missing something; it isn't working.  @user1686's entry did set me up but for the sake of... at 'home', if I run:

`home$ ssh -J intern -p 2222 localhost`

...I get:

`channel 0: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
stdio forwarding failed
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535`

Comment: After searching a bit it looks like this may have many causes and may be difficult to debug (I saw situations with similar errors being fixed by simply replacing localhost by 127.0.0.1 (!)). Since the other solution worked for you, I would go with that one for now, but if you care to debug you can add `-vvv` to your ssh command and see if the debug logs give some more hints.